# in urn A white balls and B black balls. what would be the probability of taking the 5th ball being white

Tags: probability, combinatorics

the problem goes like that "in urn $A$ white balls, $B$ black balls. we take out without returning 5 balls. (we assume $A,B\gt4$) what would be the probability that at the 5th ball removal, there was a white ball while we know that at the 3rd was a black ball".

What I did is I build a conditional probability tree. as it seemed, it gets really ugly and parameters won't reduce, so the equation is huge, therefor probably it's not the correct path of solution.

I've got this intuition that the probability of the **p**th ball removal being black while **q**th ball removal being white is the same as the probability of the first ball being black, and the second ball being white - $\frac{A}{A+B-1}$ but this is only intuition and I can't explain it.

would appreciate your advising,

Comment: Why not first try with a number example? Pick for $A$ and $B$ a not too big number and try to see a pattern

Comment: @imranfat I did it, and I saw it worked. that's where I got the intuition from. my problem is to explain/prove it in global for $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just imagine them all placed randomly  in a row, their position won't change by extraction.

Then P(a black ball is in **any** position) $=\frac{B}{A+B}$,

and P(a white ball is in **any** position) $= \frac{A}{A+B}$.

- P(get a black ball on p−th extraction) $=\frac{B}{A+B}$
- For P(get a black ball on p−th extraction and white on q−th extraction), the logic is more subtle, the probabilities of a $B-W$ pair occupying any  two positions will be the same, hence the same as $B-W$ occupying positions $1$ and $2$, $=\frac{AB}{(A+B)(A+B-1)}$

---

*ADDED*

If you are asking the conditional probability of the q-th ball being white, given that the p-th was black, $(q>p), $it will, of course, be $\dfrac{A}{A+B-1}$

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways you could draw 5 balls with the 3rd being black is $B(A+B-1)_4$, where $(n)_r=n(n-1)\ldots (n-r+1)$. That's $B$ choices for the 3rd ball, and any length 4 sequence of the remaining $A+B-1$ balls. Similarly, the number of ways you could draw with the 3rd black and the 5th white is $AB(A+B-2)_3$. Divide them to get your formula.